# Change Data Capture cannot be enabled on a table with a clustered columnstore index. Consider dropping clustered columnstore index

Tags: sql-server, cdc, columnstore

I am getting the below error when trying to enable CDC on a table with a clustered columnstore index:

> Change Data Capture cannot be enabled on a table with a clustered columnstore index. Consider dropping clustered columnstore index

But I need to have both CDC and clustered columnstore index on the same table.

Is there any workaround to this limitation?

Comment: *"Consider dropping clustered columnstore index"*.

Comment: @Larnu, but I need both CDC and clustered columnstore index on the same table

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The workaround to this is to enable CDC first and then to create a clustered columnstore index.

1. Drop a clustered columnstore index if exists.
2. Enable CDC.
3. Create a clustered columnstore index.

Voila! It works!